# AngularJS, _spPageContextInfo is not defined

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

I am trying to add userName use AngularJs into Sharepoint. Also, i should have a feature that I should view all the userName from SharePoint list. But i keeping getting error says '_spPageContextInfo is not defined'.
I am just start learning SharePoint and AngularJs. Can someone help me with it? Thank you.

Here is the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- modules -->
<script src="app.js"></script> 
<!-- controllers -->
<script src="view.js"></script>
<script src="add.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<h3>view</h3>
<div class="view" ng-controller="viewItemsController" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <!-- {{user.ID}}:  -->
    {{user.Title}}, {{user.FirstName}},{{user.LastName}} 
    <br />
</div>

<hr>

<h3>add</h3>
<div class="add" ng-controller="addItemsController">
    <div class="Table">
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">Title :</div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="title" ng-model="title" />
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">First Name :</div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">Last Name :</div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" id="lastName" ng-model="lastName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell"></div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="button" id="btnAddContact" value="Add Name" ng-click="addContact()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js   //this is module

```
var spApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

view.js   // first controller

```
spApp.controller("viewItemsController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Users')/items?$select=Title,First_Name,Last_Name";
$http(
{
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
}
).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data.d.results;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
});

});
```

add.js  // second controller

```
spApp.controller("addItemsController",function($scope,$http){
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Users')/items";
var vm = $scope;
vm.addContact = function () {
    return $http({
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'Title': vm.title,
            'First_Name': vm.firstName,
            'Last_Name':vm.lastName
        }
    })
    .then(saveContact)
    .catch(function (message) {
        console.log("addContact() error: " + message);
    });
    function saveContact(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("User Added Successfully");
        return data.data.d;
    }
}

});
```

EDIT:
After check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791740/connect-angularjs-to-sharepoint-2010-list?rq=1), I am able to run my app now. Help this link could help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious, to me at least, what you are doing with index.html.

_spPageContextInfo will only be available on a SharePoint hosted page (i.e. script editor webpage, page layout, sharepoint designer edited page).

It will only be available once SP.js has excuted (See SharePoint scripts on demand).

If you are trying to do proper best practise sharepoint web development then look into SharePoint SPFX

I hope this is helpful